# SQL Server: Why isn't this logic working when Chunking on inserts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, chunking

Fellow Techies--

I've got an endless loop condition happening here. Why is @@rowcount never getting set back to 0? I must not be understanding what @@rowcount really does--or I am setting the value in the wrong place. I think the value should be decrementing on each pass until I eventually hit zero.

```
 DECLARE @ChunkSize int = 250000;

 WHILE @ChunkSize <> 0
 BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

     INSERT TableName
      (col1,col2)
     SELECT TOP (@ChunkSize)
      col1,col2
     FROM TableName2

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    SET @ChunkSize = @@ROWCOUNT

   END -- transaction block

 END -- while-loop block
```

Comment: scsimon, no i want to break out of the loop when the @chunksize decrements to zero, only that hasn't worked out! :)

Comment: What's the logic with select top(@ChunkSize)?

Comment: its like saying select top (250000) rows from t2 to insert into t1. @@rowcount is the mssql engine variable that i thought was keeping track of the whole possible result set--but maybe not.

Comment: Ok is ee now... this makes more sense. I'll edit in a second

Comment: there will always be records in Table2 so it won't ever end though, unless you keep track of what rows you have already accessed in this table, no?

Comment: And you are using TOP but you don't have an order by. Without an order by you don't even know which rows you will get.

Comment: Sean! Thanks so much! I knew I forgot something. It is indeed the order by! This should work a whole lot better in about 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm interested in the solution when you get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implemented solution**

In the end, I decided to pump the SQL through SSIS, where I could set the commit batch size accordingly.  Had I not chosen hat route, I would have had to follow @scsimon's suggestion and basically maintain a tracking table for the records completed and the records left to cycle through.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, by what you posted, how you are going to ensure you catch rows that you haven't already inserted. If you don't, it'll be an infinite loop of course. Here is a way using test data--but naturally you'd want to base it off a PK or other unique column. Perhaps you just left that part off, or I'm missing something all together. I'm just interested in what your final code is for your chunking and the logic behind it, so this is an answer and inquiry.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#source') is not null drop table #source
if object_id('tempdb..#destination') is not null drop table #destination

create table #source(c1 int, c2 int)
create table #destination (c1 int, c2 int)

insert into #source (c1,c2) values
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,1),
(6,1),
(7,1),
(8,1),
(9,1),
(10,1),
(11,1),
(12,1)


 DECLARE @ChunkSize int = 2;

 WHILE @ChunkSize <> 0
 BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #destination (c1,c2)
        SELECT TOP (@ChunkSize) c1,c2 FROM #source WHERE c1 NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT c1 FROM #destination) ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C1)
        SET @ChunkSize = @@ROWCOUNT

    --SELECT @ChunkSize
 END 

 select * from #source
 select * from #destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is happening because you're setting chunksize to itself without ever looking at what you've already inserted.  Using your example, `@Chunksize = 250000`.  First, select performs `SELECT TOP 250000` and returns (presumably) 250000 rows.  You then use `@@RowCount` to update `@Chunksize`, but the row count returned will be 250000, so you just set it to 250000 again.  Which could be fine, except there is no way that number will ever change without ruling out rows that you've already inserted - you will keep inserting the same 250000 rows over and over.

You need something like `NOT EXISTS` to filter out the rows you've already inserted:

```
DECLARE @ChunkSize int = 250000;

WHILE @ChunkSize > 0
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

   INSERT INTO TableName
    (col1,col2)
   SELECT TOP (@ChunkSize)
    col1,col2
   FROM TableName2 T2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   TableName T
                     WHERE  T.Col1 = T2.Col1
                     AND    T.Col2 = T2.Col2)

  SET @ChunkSize = @@ROWCOUNT
  PRINT CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@ChunkSize) + ' Rows Inserted.';

  COMMIT TRANSACTION

END -- while-loop block
```

Comment: Glad I wasn't the only one that saw it that way

Comment: closer, no more infinite loops--but once the first 250000 get written that will be all that gets written. I guess @@rowcount isn't what i thought. it looks like i'll need the row count of t2 and decrement from that until each chunk is completed.

Comment: @plditallo did you test my syntax below? It works as you expected chunking two rows at a time for my example... It will remain the same  until it's done, with the exception of the final select which can be less than the original chunk size

Comment: @plditallo Oh duh, you're right.  That's because of the transaction setup. Updated my answer.  The rowcount value is lost when the transaction is committed.